# Flutter: Value of List<File> can't be assigned to a variable of type List<Widget>

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to map selected images so that I can display them in the build.

I have:

```
 // declared earlier
List<File> _images;

List<Widget> image = _images
      if (_images != null) {
      _images.map((c) => new Image.file(c)
      ).toList();
```

Which is giving me the following error:

```
'List<File>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Widget>'.
```

I understand the error, File cannot be assigned to Widget, however I have no idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here `List<Widget> image = _images`.

Try

```
List<Widget> imageWidgets = _images.map<Image>((c) => new Image.file(c)).toList();
```

Comment: Indeed it must be that how I create the list. Thank you for the answer! That however just changes the error message into: type 'List<Image>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: Actually nevermind :). My bad later in the code. Works perfectly, thank you!